# Cross platform development with a single working copy

Tags: windows, macos, cross-platform

We are doing some cross platform development on OSX with Paralells installed with different Windows versions.  Has anyone found a good solution to share a single working copy/code base instead of having to check out different copies on each operating system?

Comment: I believe your question is more about how to arrange a code for better cross platform development and minimize redundant code and files. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought would be distributed version control, such as Git or Mercurial. But that gives you a shared repository, not a shared working copy.

What about exposing a directory as a shared network drive and connecting to it from the other virtual environments?

Comment: VM+shared files => network drive or VM-software specific shared folders.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using dropbox for this. Nothing stops you from having  your files in version control and dropbox at the same time. I've discovered that this approach produces faster compile times than mounting a networked file system (e.g. with SMB, NFS or sshfs).

The key is to configure your build system for out-of-source builds. 
CMake is one build system that makes this trivial: 
http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#What_is_an_.22out-of-source.22_build.3F

If modifying your build system is not an option, one possible alternative is to put all your source files in a separate dropbox-synced directory and just sym-link it in your regular build tree.